# phonegap create a bitmap from html

Tags: android, cordova, bitmap, android-webview

how can you create a bitmap from the html in the screen of the device?

I tried this but it gives me a black image output

```
Webview mAppView = this.webView;
float appScale = mAppView.getScale();

int scaledViewHeight = (int)(webViewHeight * appScale);
int scaledViewWidth = (int)(webViewWidth * appScale);

bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledViewWidth, scaledViewHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM/Camera/" + "canvas.png");
    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, os);

    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.v("save image", "fail"); 
    }
```

Comment: You need to pass the url from the image to method that does a url to bitmap transformation, or possibly get the base64 data and create bitmap from that, not sure if that works in Android.

Comment: My problem is I cannot use the android native to combine to images for they are too large and get a memory error, thus I created a canvas where i combined the 2 images. I am trying to make it compatible to lower android versions since toDataURL does not work on them, got the idea from http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/html5-canvas-todataurl-support-for-android-devices-working-phonegap-2-2-0-plugin/#comment-2981